# Prove that $S_n$, with $n \geq 3$, any even permutation is a product of cycles of length three.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Prove that $S_n$, with $n \geq 3$, any even permutation is a product of cycles of length three.

We consider $\sigma=\underbrace{(a,b)\dots(x,y)}_{2n}$

I am stuck here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
(a,b)(c,d) = \\
(a,b)[(b,c)(b,c)](c,d) =\\
[(a,b)(b,c)][(b,c)(c,d)]=\\
(a,b,c)(b,c,d)
$$